# Symbolic Link Permission Denied in /var/www

Tags: php, apache, permissions, file-permissions, symlink

I'm having some issues with permissions when it comes to symbolic links on my apache2 webserver.  I originally had a data/ in /var/www , but was it getting too large for the directory and I kept getting a partition full warning.  I'd like to move the data/ folder to /home/processor/Documents/sandbox/www_data/

I moved all the data to www_data and created a symbolic link in /var/www

```
ln -s /home/processor/Documents/sandbox/www_data data
```

Checking the link:

```
:/var/www$ ls -l data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 processor processor 43 Mar 16 17:03 data -> /home/processor/Documents/sandbox/www_data/
```

An example of the data shows that all permissions seem reasonable to me:

```
:/var/www$ ls -l data/2/15/2015/8/25/10/54/wf/2_15_2015_8_25_10_54_11*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 processor processor 475643 Mar 16 16:58 data/2/15/2015/8/25/10/54/wf/2_15_2015_8_25_10_54_11.png
-rwxrwxrwx 1 processor processor  53539 Mar 16 16:58 data/2/15/2015/8/25/10/54/wf/2_15_2015_8_25_10_54_11_thumb.png
```

This is whats in between the `<VirtualHost *:80> </VirtualHost>` in my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

But when trying too access it from the site I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /data/2/15/2015/8/25/9/46/wf/2_15_2015_8_25_9_46_28.png on this server."

I've read through a bunch of threads and have chown www-data:www-data, I've chmod -R 777 everything, and changed my 000-default.conf to numerous varieties of the same thing, but nothing is working.  I don't know where to go from here.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the permissions of /home/processor.  The entire path needs a certain degree of privileges and the home directory did not have them. The only thing that needed to be done was to allow access to read and execute

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/processor/
```

Comment: Thanks! This was just what I needed. After doing all sorts of regular chmods like you first tried as well, this did the trick.